# I get this error : Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am getting this error for some reason, and I can't find a solution.

```
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as get] (C:\Users\Arian\Desktop\schools API practice\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Arian\Desktop\schools API practice\routes\schoolRouter.js:8:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Arian\Desktop\schools API practice\app.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Arian\Desktop\schools API practice\server.js:7:13)
```

I am directly copying off jonas's node.js course on udemy, except replacing tours with schools, because I am trying to practice on my own.

here's schoolRouter.js

```
const express = require("express");
const schoolController = "../controllers/schoolController";

const router = express.Router();

router
  .route("/")
  .get(schoolController.getAllSchools)
  .post(schoolController.createSchool);

router
  .route("/:id")
  .get(schoolController.getSchool)
  .patch(schoolController.updateSchool)
  .delete(schoolController.deleteSchool);

module.exports = router;
```

and here's schoolController.js

```
const School = require("../models/schoolModel");
const APIFeatures = require("apifeatures");

exports.getAllSchools = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const schools = await School.find();

    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      results: schools.length,
      data: schools,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: err,
    });
  }
};

exports.createSchool = (req, res) => {};

exports.getSchool = (req, res) => {};

exports.updateSchool = (req, res) => {};

exports.deleteSchool = (req, res) => {};
```

edit (2): schoolModel.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const schoolSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "A school must have a name"],
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: "public school",
    trim: true,
    required: [true, "A school type must be defined"],
  },
  images: {
    type: [],
  },
  teacherCount: {
    type: Number,
    min: [1, "There must be atleast one teacher"],
  },
  streetName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  ratingsAverage: {
    type: Number,
    min: [0, "Minimum rating is 0"],
    max: [5, "Maximum rating is 5"],
  },
  studentCount: {
    type: Number,
    min: [1, "A school must have at least one student"],
  },
  builtOn: {
    type: Number,
  },
});

const School = mongoose.model("School", schoolSchema);

module.exports = School;
```

I thought it might also have to do with the server.js js file, but most errors similar to this don't relate much to it.

edit(3): app.js file:

```
const express = require("express");

const schoolRouter = require("./routes/schoolRouter");

const app = express();

app.use("/api/schools", schoolRouter);

// start server
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Did you save both files? I know it sounds simple but that is sometime the cause

Comment: yeah XD, I've done it a couple of times

Comment: hmm, can you show us your main server file code? To be more clear the file that is connecting all your routes together

Comment: I'll edit my question

Comment: I meant the file where your schoolRouter.js file is imported

Comment: I just re edited the file

Comment: not your model but where your schoolRouter.js file is imported, the last edit didn't contain any routes. 

if I read your last code correctly it should be your app.js file not your server.js

Comment: I put it in the question as another edit

Comment: Ummm... You have `schoolController` set as a string in your file, `schoolRouter.js`.

Comment: uhhhhh, welp. Thats stupid. thanks for the help man. It looks like it's my prettierrc file that is reformating it whenever I save for some reason, I guess I'll check it out